# Sitecore 7 - logout session when browser window shuts down

Tags: session, timeout, persistence, sitecore, sitecore7

in my Sitecore 6.2 Project :

- open browser window and login to sitecore content editor
- shut down browser window
- open browser window again
- I have been logged out. I need to login again

But, in my sitecore 7 project, after I shut the browser window and open it again, I dont need to login again. My session is still active.

With the 2 projects, I have the same configuration.

I have tried the Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout and Authentication.SessionTimeout Settings but it didnt help.

Does anyone know what I need to configure in Sitecore 7 so that shutting down browser window causes a logout?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this with Sitecore 7.0 (Initial Release) using IE9, Chrome (latest) and FireFox (latest).
In all cases, I need to re-login after I completely close my browser.

In what case does it not work for you? (what browser and Sitecore revision)
Are you completely exiting your browser of just closing a tab?
Mind that closing a tab does not end your session.

Comment: Hi Ruud. That was it. I was only closing the tab and expecting that the session would be ending. Anyway, your answer resolves the question. Do you know how I can get the logout processors to get called when I shut down the browser? Is it possible at all?

Comment: One approach would be to implement some custom JavaScript in the Sitecore Client that acts on the window.close event and then do a request to the logout.aspx page.